# Iterate a variable within an else if condition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, if-statement

I'm trying to create an if statement with the condition depending on a variable object. How can I go about this?

Here is the gist of what I'm trying to do...

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{       
    if (somecondition)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImage.frame, **anyOfTheImagesInMyArray**.frame))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }   
}
```

How can I get the else if condition to check more than one UIView frame before testing true or false?

**Updated Code:**

*What do I do in this case?*

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{       
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImage.frame, **anyOfTheImagesInMyArray_1**.frame))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImage.frame, **anyOfTheImagesInMyArray_2**.frame))
    {
        if (condition) {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if (condition){
            //do something else
        }
    }   
    else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImage.frame, **anyOfTheImagesInMyArray_3**.frame))
    {
        if (condition) {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if (condition){
            //do something else
        }
    }   
    else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImage.frame, **anyOfTheImagesInMyArray_4**.frame))
    {
        if (condition) {
            //do stuff
        }
        else if (condition){
            //do something else
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got the question right, but if you want to perform some tasks on every image in the array it should look e.g. like this:

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    // imagesArray is an NSArray holding UIImages
    for (UIImage *image in imagesArray) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImage.frame, image.frame)) {
            if (someCondition) {
                // do stuff
            } else {
                // do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I apply this to an else if condition only, rather than the whole if statement? Can you put an else if condition in a for loop?

Comment: I should have been a lot more specific with my current need. I'm sorry. I updating my question with something closer to what my code looks like.

Comment: Updated the code again, but if you need different if/else bodies for each image, there's really no easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do what you're trying to do with existing syntax succinctly. Instead, consider categorizing `NSArray`to add a method such as `-containsIntersectingRect:(CGRect)rect`, which loops through the array of `NSValue` objects—arrays can only contain objects, so you will have to insert your `CGRect`s into the array wrapped as `NSValue` objects—and looks for at least one positive case for `CGRectIntersectsRect`.

This will at least make the syntax more collected and abstracted into a single method for your series of conditionals.